# Issue in Receive Pipeline

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I followed the article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/biztalk/UnzipDisassembler.aspx?fid=1607856
to create a custom component that can be used in Receive pipeline.
It doesnt work.
Are there any other steps to be followed to implement this custom component?

Comment: Can you not be more specific other than "It doesnt work" ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify the issue you have, if it is the unzipping or other.

One thing I see is if your solution needs the messagetype you also have to add the common "xml disassembler" in the disassembler stage, just after the "unzip disassembler". Otherwise the message type will not be promoted and subscribers will not get the resulting message.

Regards
Martin